# How to plot a 3D looking barchart using Matplotlib in a 2D environment?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, stacked-chart

**Background**
There are several questions addressing how one can plot 3D data on a 3D plot using matplotlib. Such as [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209033/plotting-3d-barchart-from-a-3d-list) and [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086972/stacked-3d-bar-chart-with-matplotlib)

What I want is, a 3D looking stacked bar chart using a 2D data. Such stacked plots can be created using other tools conveniently (LibreOffice Calc) e.g.

---

[image: 3D looking stacked barchart produced using LibreOffice Calc].

---

**Problem**

How can I produce similar 3D effect using Matplotlib in a 2D plot. I have produced a 2D stacked barchart using Matplotlib as shown below

[image: Stacked Bar Chart 2D looks]

To be specific, I am looking to get information regarding packages/tools/themes/options that would allow me to achieve this in a 2D plot environment.

---

**Additional information**

1. Generalized code used to produce this 2D plot is as follows:

   ```
   ax.bar(X, Y1, alpha=1, label="Y1", hatch='/', color='r')
   ax.bar(X, Y2, bottom=Y1, alpha=1, label="Y2", color='g', hatch='.')
   ax.bar(X, Y3, bottom=Y1+Y2, alpha=1, label="Y3", hatch='\\', color='b')
   ```
2. Data used to create this is given

[image: here]

3. Using  [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086972/stacked-3d-bar-chart-with-matplotlib), by setting the y-axis to be constant, I have produced the following plot (Thanks to the community members for helping me in refining the question)

[image: 3D plot by setting Y-axis to be constant]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacked 3d bar chart with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086972/stacked-3d-bar-chart-with-matplotlib)

Comment: I agree, you can stack the dz values while keeping the y position constant.

Comment: @SilverMonkey I had already mentioned it in the background. I was wondering if there was a direct tool/package/theme/plot type which would allow me to circumvent this process.

Comment: @tianlinhe I have edited the question to address your comment. Thank you.

Comment: @neeraj not any that I know. But you may actually produce one, package it and call it each time.